# Error: 'Imported XML Content cannot be parsed'

Tags: google-sheets

Here's what I'm doing:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.predictit.org/api/marketdata/markets/7164", "/MarketData/Contracts/MarketContract/ID")
```

The other answers I've seen about this have said that Javascript would be the issue, but the page in question seems to load without it, and I've tried using IMPORTJSON and IMPORTFROMWEB to no avail.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You are input incorrect parameter for the `xmlpath`, a proper formula should be as following and you need to spend sometime to find the correct `xmlpath` to extract the specific string or information you want,

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.predictit.org/api/marketdata/markets/7164","//a/@href")
```

Here is one example from Google:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moon_landing", "//a/@href")
```

Comment: I copied the XML path of the element from Inspect Element, so I'm not sure where I went wrong.

Comment: The website is invalid, do you try in browser first?

Comment: https://www.predictit.org/api/marketdata/markets/7164 is the site, which works fine for me.

Comment: I guess it is intranet? Because i cannot access to the website